# How can a verb be in the beginning of a sentence when it is usually at the end? Ex. 折れた淡い翼。

Tags: grammar, verbs, readings, relative-clauses

When composing sentences in Japanese, the verb tends to be last right? For example,

バナナを食べました。 --> I ate a banana

But recently I came across a sentence where the verb was at the beginning of the the sentence.

折れた淡い翼。

How is this possible? 「折れた」 means "broken; bended," would it translate as " broken fleeting wings"?

This is the first line in a song that I am trying to translate. The first verse is as follows:

> 折れた淡い翼
>
> きみは少し青すぎる空につかれただけさ
>
> もう誰かのためじゃなくて
>
> 自分のために笑っていいよ

I am not worried about the translation but rather why the verb is in the beginning of the sentence and why there is no need for 「を」.

Thank you!

Comment: OT, but, a tip while you're here, if you're doing songs. Discard any preconceptions you might have of Japanese lyrics being nonsensical. Often they are, but it's awful when people butcher a meaningful song because they expect shallow/meaningless lyrics. This group (Aqua Timez)'s songs in particular, mostly always tell a cohesive story. Within each verse there are cohesive thoughts whose grammar spans multiple lines (e.g.: 時にこの世界は // 上を向いて // 歩くには少し眩しすぎるね, all one sentence). A line break is not a full stop or even a space. Always consider metaphor and the bigger picture. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: As you said, it's *usually* at the end.

Answer (score 7):

It happens in sentences where the verb acts kind of like an adjective. I mean, not exactly but here is an example:

In English you might say "The person I met yesterday" which turns into "昨日会った人" (きのうあったひと) in Japanese or "The banana I ate yesterday" => "昨日食べたバナナ"。I think this is called noun phrase in English.

The important thing about this is that it's one complete part of a sentence. So if you have "I want to meet X again" you can replace X with "the person I met yesterday":

"X また会いたい"　=> "昨日会った人にまた会いたい"

Hope this helps.

Comment: 昨日会った人また会いたい is ungrammatical.  If you want to say “I want to see the person I met yesterday again,” it is 昨日会った人にまた会いたい.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Thanks for pointing it out! I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, it's not a complete sentence. It looks a lot like a song title.

`折れた淡い翼だ` would be a properly formed sentence, if a somewhat odd one in isolation.

One of the things you can do with plain-form sentences in Japanese is use them to modify nouns. In Japanese, there's a general rule that when X modifies noun Y, the ordering is "X, then Y".

A sentence ending in Xだ changes to modify noun Y with XのY (usually).

A verb or i-adjective simply uses its plain form directly before the noun Y.

In this case, both the adjective (淡い) and the past-tense verb (折れた) modify the same noun (翼).

Comment: You are correct. It is the first line in a song.